# Access shadow properties in IMaterializationInterceptor

Tags: entity-framework-core

Using the the new `IMaterializationInterceptor`, is it possible to access shadow properties of executed queries? When inspecting the query string with `ToQueryString()` I can see that all shadow properties are queried, but they are `null` when accessed in the interceptor.

```
public class MyInterceptor : IMaterializationInterceptor
{
   public object InitializedInstance(MaterializationInterceptionData materializationData, object instance)
   {
      var entry = materializationData.Context.Entry(instance);
      entry.CurrentValues["SomeOtherProperty"] = entry.CurrentValues["MyShadowProperty"];
   }
}
```

Comment: `materializationData.GetPropertyValue("SomeOtherProperty")` ?

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, thanks. If you post it as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During interception object is not yet registered in ChangeTracker and you cannot access Entry values. For this situation new interception API has `MaterializationInterceptionData` instance as parameter which contains values retrieved from database.

Using this class you can access to Shadow Property values:

```cs
materializationData.GetPropertyValue("MyShadowProperty");
```